# Sending Table data as report to mail with the sql job done status?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to generate  every day report of the users added on that particular day ,and this should be sent as mail  with sql job after the job is successfully completed?
                      Is it possible ? If yes..Let me know the solution guys...

Answer (score 1):

You can send emails by using sp_send_dbmail... You can query data directly from a database and send the results as either an attachment or embedded in the body of the mail.

See [sp_send_dbmail in BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx). You'll need to make sure db mail has been set up in order for this to work.